# Error in saving multiple rows with same value in a column of composite key table in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My entity models:

```
 [Table("Student")]
   public class Students
   {
       [Key]
       public int id { get; set; }
       public string Student_name{ get; set; }
   }

[Table("StudentInSubjects")]
public class Subjects
{
       [Key]
       //public int id { get; set; }
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
       public int StudentId { get; set; }
       public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}
```

I know that an entity model in asp.net requires a `column/id` as key which will be auto incremented (identity specification to `yes` in MySQL server).

Otherwise entity model will search for a key.

But in above model I don't want to add any other column as key. When `Key` is not used then error shows that `not defined any key`. But when `key` is used in `SubjectId` then it only accept unique value, where I need multiple rows with same values.

As a result in `SaveChanges()` method this error occurs:

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an
>   error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext
>   might be in an inconsistent state.
>
> Inner exception message:
>   AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict
>   with another object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key
>   values are unique before calling AcceptChanges

My table will contain two columns (`StudentId`, `SubjectId`) that are a composite key.

Now my question: is there any other way to save row without adding another column as key in the table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the alternative solution. I just added `[key]` and `[column(Order=OrderNumber)]` as below to treat as `composite key` in the entity model:

```
   [Table("StudentInSubjects")]
   public class Subjects
    {
       [Key]
       [Column(Order = 0)]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
       public int StudentId { get; set; }

       [Key]
       [Column(Order = 1)]
       public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks